# Qual é o erro no programa?

Tags: java, android

Da-me um erro no qual o `R` aparece a vermelho.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //reference to xml widgets
        final TextView FishText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FishText);
        Button ChangeNameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeNameButton);

        final String animais[] = new String[5];
        animais[0]="Dog";
        animais[1]="Cat";
        animais[2]="Rat";
        animais[3]="Horse";
        animais[4]="Mouse";

        //change the name of the animal 
        ChangeNameButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        for(int contador = 0;contador<5;contador++) {
                            FishText.setText(animais[contador]);
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nenhum. Você precisa dar um rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

O erro ocorre quando a Classe R do projeto não foi gerada, ou não se encontra na pasta `/res/` do projeto.
Para solucionar o problema, faça o seguinte:

**Solução 1**
Navegue até Project -> Clean -> selecione seu projeto
ou
Selecione o projeto e pressione a tecla F5 (Refresh)

**Solução 2**
Selecione o projeto, clique com o botão direito do mouse e navegue até Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties

**Solução 3**
Verifique se o Project Buid Target de sua app está configurado de acordo com seu arquivo AndroidManifest.xml através da propriedade android:minSdkVersion.
A propriedade android:minSdkVersion tem que ser igual ao API Level do Project Build Target. Quando você altera o Target de sua aplicação o plugin não modifica o arquivo de manifesto.

--- Resolução do problema do loop ---

**Troque essa parte**

```
for(int contador = 0;contador<5;contador++) {
                            FishText.setText(animais[contador]);
                        }
```

**Por essa**

```
     String [] animais = {"Dog","Cat","Rat","Horse","Mouse"};
      ArrayList<String> animaisList= new ArrayList<String> //Cria o Array com a String 
    (Arrays.asList(animaisList));
         Collections.shuffle(animaisList);   //Embaralho (Random) as posições          
 FishText.setText(String.valueOf(animaisList.get(1))); //Capituro o primeiro valor
```

Verifica se a solução atende.

Comment: Obrigado! Podia me so ajudar numa coisa ? eu fiz o que voce disse e me deu  so mouse, podia me dizer como faço para ele fazer loop por todas e ir mudando e não fazer loop e so mudar no ultimo ?

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: é necessario importar alguma coisa ? da me alguns erros

Comment: Sim, a classe java.lang.object, mais a IDE já deve solicitar a inclusão dessa classe, pega o código atualizado ai e faz o teste.
Uma solução mais simples também seria adicionar um JComboBox, com as opções dos animais, o usuário então seleciona o animal no combobox ficaria até melhor do que da forma atual, para pegar um texto de um combobox você utiliza o seguinte recurso -> nomedocombobox.getSelectedItem();